# Закрытие одного элемента при нажатии на другой

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть два два выпадающих списка, и не могу разобраться как сделать, чтобы при нажатии на один, закрывался другой список.

```
$(function(){
    $('.selected').click(function(){
        $('.option-list').slideToggle(200);
        $('.select').toggleClass('select-active');
    });
    $('.option').click(function(){
      select_val = $(this).attr('data-select-val');
      select_div = $(this).parent().parent();
      $(select_div).children('.selected').html($(this).html());
      $(select_div).children('input').val(select_val);
      
      $('.option-list').slideToggle(200);
      $('.select').toggleClass('select-active');
    });
  });

  $(function(){
    $('.selected-two').click(function(){
        $('.option-list-two').slideToggle(200);
        $('.select-two').toggleClass('select-active-two');
    });
    $('.option-two').click(function(){
      select_val = $(this).attr('data-select-val');
      select_div = $(this).parent().parent();
      $(select_div).children('.selected-two').html($(this).html());
      $(select_div).children('input').val(select_val);
      
      $('.option-list-two').slideToggle(200);
      $('.select-two').toggleClass('select-active');
    });
  });
```

Comment: А если будет 100 `selected`, вы под каждый будете писать __один и тот же__ код отдельно? Покажите пожалуйста остальной код

Comment: Пока только два

Comment: Тем не менее, они идентичны, проще же оформить его так, чтобы он стал универсальным.